Ender 3 V2 (Neo) - Large temperature fluctuations while printing leading to thermal runaway
Thermal Runoff Issue
When I try to print a part, the hotend temperature randomly fluctuates after some time, leading to a thermal runoff error and print cancellation by the printer.
What Happens
In these screenshots, the first wavy fluctuation before the green "Start" line is from me running an auto G-code PID tuning.


I did another print (failed in the same way) before PID tuning and got several drops to around -15 °C (just like the one in this graph), so maybe the tuning helped. The printer seems to always display an error that the nozzle or bed temperature is too low.
Current Setup
I am currently running Octoprint on a Raspberry Pi 4B connected to an otherwise stock Ender 3 V2 Neo with an official hotend thermistor replacement. The printer is set to the correct 115 V for my power grid.
Tried so Far
I've been experiencing similar issues for months. Sometimes the error used to also say that the nozzle or bed temperature was too high, but I haven't seen that since replacing the thermistor. So far, I've:

replaced the hotend thermistor -- fixed the original issues for a while
replaced the hotend thermistor again -- didn't seem to help this time
cleaned the small hole in which the clear thermistor bulb sits -- didn't seem to help, a lot of dust came out
tried many different positions of the wire and tightnesses of its screw  -- didn't seem to help
run an auto PID tuning with M303 E0 S200 C8 and set the new positions with M301 P19.46 I1.51 D62.78  -- maybe helped? didn't do much though

I'm not sure what to try next, any help would be appreciated!

Is it possible that it could be an issue with the outlet the printer is plugged into? I wouldn't think so, since I've moved it around a lot, but it might be having different issues now than before.
